# Create project in Visual Studio and open/run in vs code on mac

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I need to open, edit, and **debug** an ASP.NET Core project in VS Code on a **mac**. The project was created in **Visual Vtudio 2015 on a PC**.

I'm having trouble. I get the error

> No task runner configured

and it brings me to **launch.json**.

It sounds like a gulp thing and I'm not sure what I'd need gulp for... nor do I know what to do with launch.json, having come from visual studio 2015. Shouldn't it just launch in Kestral and go?

For some reason all the S/O questions and tutorials I've found through search are about creating a .Net Core project in VS Code and *maybe* opening it in Visual Studio... Not what I need. Other way around. Project created on PC in Visual Studio then open and fully develop on mac in VS Code.

Maybe my search query is wrong. Surely this isn't a new problem. Or, maybe I'm just doing something stupid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging _You should not force a tag into your title_

Comment: Tseng, I did not "force" any tag and I can't think of a better title for my question. Rather than down-voting and being cryptic maybe you could be helpful?

Comment: Look at the edit, you **did** force it in the title: "**.Net Core** - create Create project in Visual Studio and open/run in vs code on mac" The bold part is a forced tag. Read the FAQ. It's fully sufficient to put the tag into the tag section, no need to force it into the title. You can trust that most people know where to find the tag section and the people interested in a topic will monitor the tags they are interested in

Answer (score 0):

When you click Launch. Then you select dot net core on launch json option. It would create a launch.json like this:

```
https://github.com/tuoitrevohoc/NetExpress/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json
```

Then you need to edit the path to your built dll file. And click run again. Follow the guide to create a task.json to build the project. Then when you click run again it will run.